# Net::HTTP отправка запроса xml

Tags: ruby

Надобно отправить запрос в виде xml.

```
uri =URI('https://fs.example.com:8443/services/trust/13/usermixed')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request['Content-Type'] = 'application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8'
request.body = @body
response = http.request(request)
```

При отправке запроса к uri в конце метод `Net::HTTP::Post.new` подкидывает еще порт 80, в итоге получается коннект на `https://fs.example.com:8443/services/trust/13/usermixed:80` что приводит к ошибке `SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to https://fs.example.com:8443/services/trust/13/usermixed:80 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)`

В принципе подобную проблему решает метод `Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, data)` никаких левых портов... но он принимает дату только хэшем. Мне же нужно отправлять request.body в XML

Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

UPD. Версия ruby 2.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это задокументировано. [Вот что написано про `Net::HTTP::new(address, port = nil)`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-new):

> The address should be a DNS hostname or IP address

Он не принимает полные URL. Его следует конструировать так:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
```

И для совершения `POST`-запроса использовать [его метод `post`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-post):

```
http.post(uri.path, @body, 'Content-Type' => 'application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8')
```

---

Или, если вы можете себе позволить перейти на 2.4, и вы не планируете к этому же узлу совершать других запросов в ближайшее время (т. е. повторного использования объекта `http` не ожидаете), есть смысл использовать сразу [метод `Net::HTTP::post(url, data, header = nil)`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-post), пример применения которого есть даже в документации:

```
Net::HTTP.post URI('http://www.example.com/api/search'),
               { "q" => "ruby", "max" => "50" }.to_json,
               "Content-Type" => "application/json"
```

Comment: действительно..благодарю за ответ, но последний метод выкинул NoMethodError: undefined method `post' for Net::HTTP:Class... что я мог сделать не так:)

Comment: @rostov-7 хм. Другая версия Ruby, скорее всего. Уточните в вопросе и ткните меня тут, посмотрю. Или перейдите на 2 4+.

Comment: Обновлять руби ради метода в stdlib, который можно обойти или заменить одним из десятка гемов -- это не очень подход.

Comment: @Nakilon задерживаться без особых причин на устаревших версиях тоже не очень подход. Поэтому я и попросил у ТСа версию.

Comment: 2.3.1 сейчас.. попробую 2.4 . Спасибо